# How to dynamically set Link Button Text (also includes icon) using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using Link button in asp.net Server side with two condition either Add/Edit on some condition

```
    if (btnAdd.Text == "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk\></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add") 
{do someDB update}
else (btnAdd.Text == "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit")
{do someDB update}
```

Now i want to change the text of the link button using jquery from client side reset button the code of jquery of the particular line is

```
$('[id*=btnAdd]').html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk\"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add");
```

if data already exist in db then on retreival

```
btnAdd.Text == "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit"
```

else

```
btnAdd.Text == "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk\></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add"
```

now on the first time i have checked already existence data then value of btnAdd is Edit while on clicking reset button it should be "Add" but it doesn't work.

it reset only the text of the button on front but in aspx.cs file it always show 
btnAdd.Text value is

```
"<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit"
```

please suggest the solution

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best approach to compare markup. You have to add some data-, class, etc.
For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#test').on('click', function(){
                var state = jQuery(this).attr('data-state');
                if (state === 'add') {
                    jQuery(this).attr('data-state', 'edit');
                    jQuery(this).find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-floppy-disk').addClass('glyphicon-edit');
                    jQuery(this).find('.button-text').text('Edit');
                }
                else if (state === 'edit') {
                    jQuery(this).attr('data-state', 'add');
                    jQuery(this).find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-edit').addClass('glyphicon-floppy-disk');
                    jQuery(this).find('.button-text').text('Add');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" id="test" class="btn btn-default" data-state="add" aria-label="Left Align">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="button-text">Add</span>
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```